# How is DISPLAY variable defined for X access on WSL?

Tags: x11, display, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My WSL defines the DISPLAY variable for x windows on the .profile, checking the IPs I have on the resolv.conf.

Why ?  If I am not wrong, resolv.conf is only used for define the DNS to use, and the DISPLAY should point to my local IP.   In fact,  I have several (plenty) of IPs on my Windows machine due the use of VirtualBox,  Vmware, and WSL, that do their own virtual ethernet cards, and the DISPLAY that is defined by default using this profile, it does not work, I had to change it manually and assign the one I have on my main ethernet card  (I had to do a export DISPLAY=192.168.1.8:0.0  to have my X working and overwrite the value 192.168.1.1:0.0 that my DISPLAY variable get automatically when my WSL starts).

Note also that if I find my NATed Ip (using whatismyip.com to find wich one is the public IP I am using when connecting to Internet), and I try to setup my Display to that IP so I can invoke xterm on remote machines hold on AWS, it does not work either.  Why?  It does if I do a ssh -X to that remote machine with my display manually setup to 192.168.1.8:0.0.   I would like to know the reasons about a).- DISPLAY being setting automatically by profile incorrectly  b).- Public IP of my machine not working if manually setup on DISPLAY variable c).- IP mentionated previously (192.168.1.8:0.0) working fine instead the public the one.

Some additional context data:

The current profile I have has:

```
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
export DISPLAY_NUMBER="0.0"
export DISPLAY=$(grep -m 1 nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $2}'):$DISPLAY_NUMBER
```

My resolv.conf is :

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver fec0:0:0:ffff::1
search gorostidi-home.lan
```

My ifconfig:

```
andres@DCT00175:~$ ifconfig
eth3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.56.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.56.255
        inet6 fe80::1bd8:2cef:f202:d18b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0xfd<compat,link,site,host>
        ether 0a:00:27:00:00:0a  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth4: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.28.48.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.28.63.255
        inet6 fe80::f389:4534:305:8a86  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0xfd<compat,link,site,host>
        ether 00:15:5d:16:f9:f0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth5: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.250.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.250.255
        inet6 fe80::b10b:16fd:43b6:c962  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0xfd<compat,link,site,host>
        ether 0a:00:27:00:00:10  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

**eth6:** flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.8  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::2669:762c:cd7f:3da6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0xfd<compat,link,site,host>
        ether 70:b3:d5:5c:0c:a1  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth7: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.115.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.115.255
        inet6 fe80::337b:d856:e3cf:dd85  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0xfd<compat,link,site,host>
        ether 00:50:56:c0:00:01  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.23.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.23.255
        inet6 fe80::6ce0:a4cb:44b5:b58f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0xfd<compat,link,site,host>
        ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth11: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.24.16.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.24.31.255
        inet6 fe80::6319:6b32:8b9c:feeb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0xfd<compat,link,site,host>
        ether 00:15:5d:18:6c:7c  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 1500
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0xfe<compat,link,site,host>
        loop  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wifi2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.223.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.223.255
        inet6 fe80::7f7d:9903:bd01:6cb6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0xfd<compat,link,site,host>
        ether 36:c9:3d:82:2c:29  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

My current DNS and also, current router, is 192.168.1.1  (the one is setup on resolv.conf).

Thks for your help !

Comment: This looks like [https://superuser.com/a/1476160/990044](https://superuser.com/a/1476160/990044). Could it be that you copied it from somewhere and just forgot about it? I have nothing like this, `DISPLAY` is simply not set (if I don't use my bash function) and my nameserver address is 172.20.0.1 which is the address of my "Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter" as I haven't changed anything yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings in your `.profile` are yours to change as you see fit.
If the current DISPLAY setting in your `.profile` is not right for you, then you should change it to something that actually works.

> a).- DISPLAY being setting automatically by profile incorrectly

Your setup is more complex than expected by the creators of the WSL distribution you're currently using, and so its defaults don't work for you.

Getting the local IP address from a `nameserver` line in `resolv.conf` would make sense only if the IP referred to the local host that is running both the actual X11 server and a DNS resolver/proxy server. That may have been the default in a generic installation, but your customization may have broken that assumption.

Whatever the actual reason is, the fact remains that the current `DISPLAY` settings in your `.profile` are not correct *for you*, and you should adjust them to better fit your actual situation.

As Freddy said in the comments, your settings look like they might have been copied from https://superuser.com/a/1476160/990044 or some other source, back when WSL did not yet have graphics support for its own X11 server, and had to piggy-back on a X11 server running on the Windows host OS. If your WSL is up to date, having those settings in `.profile` might be entirely unnecessary with the current WSL 2.

> b).- Public IP of my machine not working if manually setup on DISPLAY variable

Your NAT does not have a port forwarding rule for port 6000/TCP (port number = display number + 6000), your local X11 server is not listening in the IP address the port forwarding points to, and/or your local software firewall (including Windows Firewall) is blocking incoming traffic to port 6000/TCP for that IP address.

> c).- IP mentionated previously (192.168.1.8:0.0) working fine instead of the public one

In that IP address, there is no firewall blocking the port 6000/TCP, and your local X11 server is listening on that port, and so the X11 clients can connect to the X11 server and access your display using that address.

---

In the X11 specification, the thing before the colon was originally specified to be the **hostname** (see `man X`). The ability to also accept IP addresses was added later, when running X11 servers on personal workstations that did not necessarily have a resolvable hostname become a reasonably common thing. (If you ever need to deal with old X11R5 client software on some legacy system, you may find it still doesn't accept an IP address in DISPLAY.)